# How To Localize a "Timer" on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I need to display a timer in "hh:mm:ss" format on the iPhone, but want it localized. Finland, for example uses a period instead of a colon between the time components (hh.mm.ss). Apple's NSDateFormatter would do the trick if I was dealing with a "time" but I need to display hours much greater than 24.

I have not been able to make an NSDate/NSDateFormatter work because when you make one with seconds...

```
NSDate *aDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:aTotalSeconds];
```

... every 86,400 seconds (one day's worth) NSDate automatically increments the day and hours, minutes, and seconds go back to zero. I need to make it work on an any number of seconds without rolling over. For example, with 86,401 seconds I want to display 24:00:01 (or 24.00.01 in Finland).

My code manages total seconds fine, so the only problem I have is the display. A simple...

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%d%@%d", hours, sepString, mins, sepString, secs]
```

... would work if I could find a way to get at a localized "sepString" (the time component separator). NSLocale does not seem to have this.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but could you be looking for the grouping separator?  It's keyed with `NSLocaleGroupingSeparator`.  See the `NSLocale` documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Justin: I think the grouping separater is the punctuation between 10^3 places, e.g. in American English the comma in 123,456,789.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a admittedly hackish way to get the time component separator for any locale. It should work on iOS 3.2 and above. I know the code can be more concise, but I turned my "maximum-verbosity" flag on to make it as readable as possible.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (NSString*)timeComponentSeparator
{
    // Make a sample date (one day, one minute, two seconds)
    NSDate *aDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:((24*60*60)+62)];

    // Get the localized time string
    NSDateFormatter *aFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [aFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
    [aFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSString *aTimeString = [aFormatter stringFromDate:aDate]; // Not using +localizedStringFromDate... because it is iOS 4.0+

    // Get time component separator
    NSCharacterSet *aCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@":-."];
    NSRange aRange = [aTimeString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:aCharacterSet];
    NSString *aTimeComponentSeparator = [aTimeString substringWithRange:aRange];    

    // Failsafe
    if ([aTimeComponentSeparator length] != 1)
    {
        aTimeComponentSeparator = @":";
    }

    return [[aTimeComponentSeparator copy] autorelease];
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is information on this topic for others who might be trying to figure out what character different areas of the world use to separate time components. I went through all of the "Region Format" settings on my iPhone - iOS version 4.1 (8B117) and I found all but seven regions use a colon (hh:mm). Here are the others (their NSLocaleCountryCode is in curly braces).

### Use a period, hh.mm

• Danish (Denmark) {DK}
• Finnish (Finland) {FI}
• Serbian Montenegro (Cyrillic) {ME}
• Serbian Montenegro (Latin) {ME}
• Serbian (Cyrillic) {RS}
• Serbian (Latin) {RS}

### Use a dash, hh-mm

• Marathi (India) {IN}

Note that India (not Marathi-India) also has the country code IN and it uses a colon. So just checking the country code is not enough, you will have to look at other NSLocale fields. I haven't gone through all the fields yet, but I suspect NSLocaleScriptCode  or NSLocaleVariantCode might differentiate them. This complexity is why Apple should expose this character to us in the SDK. I did log it in Radar, so if you agree please request it too, quantity of requests matters a lot in what they decide to do.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS8 and newer you can use [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/datecomponentsformatter).  Below is a Swift 3 example.

```
let duration: NSTimeInterval = 86401 // 24:00:01

let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()  
formatter.unitsStyle = .positional  
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]  
formatter.zeroFormattingBehavior = [.pad]

let formattedDuration = formatter.string(from: duration)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails, look at using NSLocalizedString() or NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the relevance of `NSLocalizedString()`.

Comment: Agreed, NSLocalizedString won't help. Interestingly Apple's Timer function in the Clock app does not change the separator to match the locale.

Comment: From my perspective, if you can't find a solution within the frameworks, you can use NSLocalizedString() for your separator. Granted, it'll just be a single char, but nevertheless it'll solve your problem.

Comment: This is the way to go.  Create a string in your Localizable.strings file for the format string, then for each language you want to support, create a version of the format string.  Use NSLocalizedString() to get the correct version of your format string for the user's current language, and pass that format string to +[NSString stringWithFormat:] as the first argument.  Then you always get the formatting you want.

Comment: You cannot use NSLocalizedString to do this. On the iPhone it only works for languages (not for locales). Date formatting differences are tied to a locale not a language. A language is English (en), French (fr), etc. A locale is United States (US), United Kingdom (GB), etc. For some reason strings in "en-GB" will not work on iPhone. And even if it did work there are over 240 locales and I want to support them all. That is why Apple invented NSLocale, I am just trying to see if I am missing something, or if it is true that there is no way to get a locale's time component separator.

Comment: Have you peeked at NSDateFormatter?

Comment: Yes, but it cannot display an hour greater than 23 (see initial question).

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should be using NSDateFormatter to format your dates. Apple recommends using the built-in styles available that the user can customize in the settings. The following code is straight from the apple docs:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];

[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];

[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:118800];

NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@"formattedDateString for locale %@: %@",

        [[dateFormatter locale] localeIdentifier], formattedDateString);
```

Comment: Understood, but I am NOT displaying a date, nor am I displaying a time (0:00 to 23:59). I am displaying hours, minutes, and seconds. Very simply put if the timer ran for 2 days, 3 hours, 4 minutes, and 5 seconds, I want to display 51:04:05 and I want this to use the formatting that is customary in the user's locale. I guess I will hard code the time separator as a colon and be done with it, plus put in a feature request to Apple to get at the locale's time component separator.

Comment: Sorry, should have read the question a little better! Having had a quick look through the docs I dont see a way of localising TimeIntervals directly. Assuming that DateFormatter does use the correct seperator character you could use this to find out what the separator should be for your locale. It's a bit horrible but does at least the localization settings on the iPhone.

Comment: That is a great idea, thanks. I checked, and NSDateFormatter does properly respect locale (region) in iOS so I can get the character from one. I think using the NSDateFormatterShortStyle and parsing the return string for the first non numeric character would be the safest way to do this "hack". Even if Apple adds a way in the SDK to get the time component separator, that would only be available for the latest version and I'd still need a solution for older versions of iOS.