# localizing elapsed time

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, localization

In my application I need to show elapsed time in mm:ss format. Now, we have to localize the application. How should we localize this elapsed time?

Comment: Isn't a colon the universal symbol in displaying time? 10:23 looks different in France than England?

Comment: you mean instead of 5:00 it should say "5 minutes" or "5 minutos" or whatever?

Comment: Yes... The format for French is H'h'mm and for German it is H:mm 'Uhr'.

Comment: So you're basically looking for the time component separator? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109587/how-to-localize-a-timer-on-iphone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the class NSDateFormatter:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:118800];

// Specifying a locale only for the purpose of this example
// if you don't specify one, it will use the user's locale, which is what you want
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:usLocale];

NSLog(@"Date for locale %@: %@",
      [[dateFormatter locale] localeIdentifier], [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]);
// Output:
// Date for locale en_US: 4:00 AM
```