# How to replace date component separators with other symbols?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdateformatter, nslocale

In my app I would like to allow users to select a variety of date formats that suit their preferences for displaying a date. However, I don't want to define a fixed date format, so instead I'm getting the most appropriate format for different components based on the current locale. I understand different locals may use different symbols to separate the components, but I am wondering if it would be possible to set those separator symbols while preserving the correct order of the components as appropriate for that locale.

For example, in the US the following code returns "09/06/2014" but in the UK it would be "06/09/2014", and I want to preserve that order but replace the slash with dashes or spaces. However I don't believe I can simply parse the returned String and replace instances of '/' with other characters because in some locales they probably don't use '/' (I'm not certain but it seems very likely).

```
NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("MMddyyyy", options: 0, locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())
```

Is it possible to change the date component separator character when at the same time getting the most appropriate format for the current locale?

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109587/how-to-localize-a-timer-on-iphone), although none of the answers seem particularly conclusive.

Comment: @jtbandes In that question they wanted to display the appropriate separator based on locale. In my case I want to replace the separator character with a different symbol while preserving everything else.

Comment: Yeah, and it seems like the natural way of doing that would be to find the character and replace it throughout. You might also have some fun class-dumping NSLocale or NSDateFormatter to see if you can get at it...

Comment: I think you're trying to be too general.  Just select several options and let your user pick between them, optionally changing the separator if that seems to make sense.

Comment: (Note that you can have the user separately select date and time formats and then combine them into one format where you need the combined format.)

Comment: I could allow them to select a day format, month format, etc then use `dateFormatFromTemplate` to get the appropriate string for those components they selected, but I still need a solution to replace the separator with a character they choose.

Comment: @jtbandes With that linked question, I could implement a similar solution to get the separator character then replace that from my string, but I would need to know every possible separator, which I don't and that seems like a bad solution. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went through all the available locales and checked out the short date format to determine that all languages use one of these three delimiters as of now: / . -

So to allow custom delimiters while preserving the format, I just replace those characters with the custom character. For example:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = DateFormatter.dateFormat(fromTemplate: "MMddyyyy", options: 0, locale: .current)

var output = dateFormatter.string(from: .now)
output = output.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: " ")
output = output.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: " ")
output = output.replacingOccurrences(of: "-", with: " ")
```

I'd be nice to find a better solution.

Here’s the code I used to make this determination. The set of delimiters it ultimately creates contains more than the actual delimiters, as some date components use non-numbers yet aren’t delimiters. Also note the ar_SA locale is unique as it has one instance of a character you may consider a delimiter, the Arabic comma, but you likely don’t want to replace that with a custom delimiter given its representation.

```
var delimitersSet = Set<Character>()
            
for identifier in Locale.availableIdentifiers {
    let locale = Locale(identifier: identifier)
                
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.locale = locale
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
                
    let shortDateFormat = dateFormatter.string(from: .now)
    let delimiters = Set(shortDateFormat.filter { !$0.isNumber })
    print("\(identifier): \(shortDateFormat): \(delimiters)")

    for delimiter in delimiters {
        if !delimitersSet.contains(delimiter) {
            print("Unique \(delimiter)")
        }
    }
    delimitersSet.formUnion(delimiters)
}
            
print("All possible date delimiters: \(delimitersSet)")
```

Comment: kudos for the effort of going through all the languages